# Indexing a multidimensional Numpy array with an array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

Let us say I have a Numpy array `a` with shape `(10, 10, 4, 5, 3, 3)`, and two lists of indices, `b` and `c`, of shape `(1000, 6)` and `(1000, 5)` respectively, which represent indices and partial indices for the array. I want to use the indices to access the array, producing arrays of shape `(1000,)` and `(1000, 3)`, respectively.

I know of a few ways to do this, but they're all unwieldy and rather un-pythonic, for example converting the indices to tuples or indexing each axis separately.

```
a = np.random.random((10, 10, 4, 5, 3, 3))
b = np.random.randint(3, size=(1000, 6))
c = np.random.randint(3, size=(1000, 5))

# method one

tuple_index_b = [tuple(row) for row in b]
tuple_index_c = [tuple(row) for row in c]

output_b = np.array([a[row] for row in tuple_index_b])
output_c = np.array([a[row] for row in tuple_index_c])

# method two

output_b = a[b[:, 0], b[:, 1], b[:, 2], b[:, 3], b[:, 4], b[:, 5]]
output_c = a[c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3], c[:, 4]]
```

Obviously, neither of these methods is very elegant or very easy to extend to higher dimensions. The first is also very slow, with two list comprehensions, and the second requires you to write out each axis separately. The intuitive syntax, `a[b]` returns an array of shape `(1000, 6, 10, 4, 5, 3, 3)` for some reason, likely related to broadcasting.

So, is there a way to do this in Numpy that doesn't involve so much manual labor/time?

Edit: Not really a duplicate, since this question deals with a list of multidimensional indices, and not just a single index, and has produced some useful new methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the index to a tuple where each column is a separate element and then use `__getitem__`, assuming the indices are always the first few dimensions:

```
a.__getitem__(tuple(b.T))
```

Or simply:

```
a[tuple(b.T)]
```

---

```
(a.__getitem__(tuple(b.T)) == output_b).all()
# True

(a.__getitem__(tuple(c.T)) == output_c).all()
# True

(a[tuple(b.T)] == output_b).all()
# True

(a[tuple(c.T)] == output_c).all()
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Method three:

```
output_b = a[map(np.ravel, b.T)]
output_c = a[map(np.ravel, c.T)]
```